# Multiple add_markers R plotly

Tags: r, colors, plotly, legend

I am trying to display on the same plot ( same `x.axis` and same `y.axis`) for different color of this data.

My first code :

```
fig <- plot_ly(partitions, x = ~`_Dim.1`, y = ~`_Dim.2`, name = 'Complete link : Data Scaled, K = 2', type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
              marker = list(size=12,symbol=0,color=~`_z_comp_scale`),
              hoverinfo = 'text',
              text = ~paste('</br> Pays: ', code_country)) %>%
  add_trace(marker=list(size=12,symbol=1,color=~`_z_comp`),inherit=TRUE,name="complet : K = 2") %>% 
  add_markers(marker=list(size=12,symbol=2,color=~`_z_comp2`),name="complet : K = 5") %>% 
  add_markers(marker=list(size=12,symbol=3,color=~`_z_avg_scale`),name="average : data Scaled, K = 3") %>%
  add_markers(marker=list(size=12,symbol=4,color=~`_z_avg_scale2`),name="average : data Scaled, K = 8") %>%
  add_markers(marker=list(size=12,symbol=5,color=~`_z_avg`),name="average :  K = 2") %>%
  add_markers(marker=list(size=12,symbol=6,color=~`_z_avg2`),name="average :  K = 5") %>%
  add_markers(marker=list(size=12,symbol=7,color=~`_z_ward_scale`),name="ward : data scaled, k = 2") %>%
  add_markers(marker=list(size=12,symbol=8,color=~`_z_ward`),name="ward : k = 2") %>%
  add_markers(marker=list(size=12,symbol=9,color=~`_z_ward2`),name="ward : k = 5") 

fig
```

Give me that : [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKmtA.png)

But i want change the color because for a partition with eight group it's not very clear for eyes with the actual color.

So i try this:

```
fig <- plot_ly(partitions, x = ~`_Dim.1`, y = ~`_Dim.2`, name = 'Complete link : Data Scaled, K = 2', type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
              size=12,symbol=0,colors=couleurs,color=~`_z_comp_scale`,
              hoverinfo = 'text',
              text = ~paste('</br> Pays: ', code_country)) %>%
  add_markers(marker=list(),size=12,symbol=0,colors=couleurs,color=~`_z_comp`,name="complet : K = 2") %>% 
  add_markers(size=12,symbol=0,colors=couleurs,color=~`_z_comp2`,name="complet : K = 5") %>% 
  add_markers(size=12,symbol=3,colors=couleurs,color=~`_z_avg_scale`,name="average : data Scaled, K = 3") %>%
  add_markers(size=12,symbol=3,colors=couleurs,color=~`_z_avg_scale2`,name="average : data Scaled, K = 8") %>%
  add_markers(size=12,symbol=3,colors=couleurs,color=~`_z_avg`,name="average :  K = 2") %>%
  add_markers(size=12,symbol=3,colors=couleurs,color=~`_z_avg2`,name="average :  K = 5") %>%
  add_markers(size=12,symbol=2,colors=couleurs,color=~`_z_ward_scale`,name="ward : data scaled, k = 2") %>%
  add_markers(size=12,symbol=2,colors=couleurs,color=~`_z_ward`,name="ward : k = 2") %>%
  add_markers(size=12,symbol=2,colors=couleurs,color=~`_z_ward2`,name="ward : k = 5") 
fig <- fig %>% layout(legend = l)
fig
```

The result is this: [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ucSQ.png)

I want to delete the the topside of legend.

I think i'am very close to my goal, any help please? thank you for your attention.

Max Mamazita

Comment: can you show us what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, sorry when i double click on the legend the topside disappears

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15WWy.png)

On this plot, 
the colors make it possible to clearly differentiate each group but the concern is at the level of the legend. Each add_markers appears at the top of the legend. It's not pretty :(